# Is it wrong to use the same ad id for multiple apps?

Tags: admob

Say I have an ad ID registered on Admob. Is it ok to use the app id for multiple apps on the Google Play Store? Would they ban my account for this?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. But.

But it is difficult to manage your application's banners if you use only a one app id.
Better is to use different banners ids for different banner formats. E.g., banners and interstitials should have different ids due to they have dramatically different eCPMs. And so on.

The better approach is to merge your admob with the firebase application in order to improve eCPM.